# How to fix 'ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined' in ANGULAR

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-services, angular-ngmodel

i'm trying to edit user with angular and laravel ,so i'm trying to passing user from front-end to back-end but i faced this error

I'm using angular material with this project

edit-user-dialog.component.ts:

```
 import { Component, OnInit ,Inject } from '@angular/core';
import {MatDialogModule} from '@angular/material/dialog';
import {
  UsersService
} from 'src/app/services/users.service';
import {
  MatDialogRef,
  MAT_DIALOG_DATA,
  MatTableDataSource
} from '@angular/material';
import { User } from 'src/app/Models/User';
import {
  ToastrService
} from 'ngx-toastr';
import { DialogData } from 'src/app/products/add-product/add-product.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-edit-user-dialog',
  templateUrl: './edit-user-dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./edit-user-dialog.component.css']
})
export class EditUserDialogComponent implements OnInit {
  User:User;

  constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef < EditUserDialogComponent > ,
    // tslint:disable-next-line: max-line-length
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA)  public data: any, private toast: ToastrService, private userservice: UsersService, ) { }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
  onNoClick(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
}
EditUser()
{
  let user: User;
  user.id = this.data.user.id
  user.username = this.User.username
  user.firstname = this.User.firstname
  user.lastname = this.User.lastname
  user.address = this.User.address
  user.emailaddress = this.User.emailaddress
  console.log(User);
  this.userservice.EditUser(User).subscribe(data => {
    this.toast.success('Success', 'Order edited!')
    this.dialogRef.close();
    //this.isLoading = false;
}, error => this.toast.error('Error', 'error.message'));
}

}
```

edit-user-dialog.component.html:

```
     <div class="control-panel">


   <form class="example-form">


  <table class="example-full-width" cellspacing="0">
     <tr>
          <td><mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
            <input matInput placeholder="Username"[(ngModel)]="User.username">
          </mat-form-field></td>
      </tr> 
    <tr>
    <td><mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
      <input matInput placeholder="First name" [(ngModel)]="User.firstname">
    </mat-form-field></td>
    <td><mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
      <input matInput placeholder="Last name" [(ngModel)]="User.lastname">
    </mat-form-field></td>
  </tr></table>

  <p>
    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
      <textarea matInput placeholder="Address" [(ngModel)]="User.address"></textarea>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
      <textarea matInput placeholder="Emial Address" [(ngModel)]="User.emailaddress"></textarea>
    </mat-form-field>
  </p>

  <button mat-fab color="warn" (click)="EditUser(User)">Edit User</button>
</form>
```

users.service.ts:

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UsersService {
  public token: string = sessionStorage.getItem('token');
  public resID: string = sessionStorage.getItem('ID');
  private _UsersUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users";
  private _EditUserUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/user/";
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }



  getUsers() : Observable<any>{

    let headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.token ,
    });
    let option = { headers: headers };
    return this.http.get<any>(this._UsersUrl , option).pipe()
  };
  EditUser(User) : Observable<any>{

    let headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.token ,
    });
    let option = { headers: headers };
    return this.http.put<any>(this._UsersUrl + User.id , option).pipe()
  };


}
```

How can i fix this error and passing user to laravel

Comment: What line is the error and which file..

Comment: the error in ts file , here :   user.username = this.User.username

Answer (score 0):

You never initialize the property User of EditUserDialogComponent.

instead of

```
export class EditUserDialogComponent implements OnInit {
  User:User;
```

try this

```
export class EditUserDialogComponent implements OnInit {
  User:User = new User();
```

If the User model is an interface not a class try something like that:

```
export class EditUserDialogComponent implements OnInit {
  User:User = {username: null, firstname: null, lastname: null,  ...};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it to this:

```
let user: User = {
  id = this.data.user.id
  username: this.User.username
  firstname: this.User.firstname
  lastname: this.User.lastname
  address: this.User.address
  emailaddress: this.User.emailaddress
};
```

`let user: User` does not instantiate the user object. If merely defines the var `user` of type `User`

Also, nowhere in your code do you actually instantiate `this.User` so you likely need `User:User = new User();` in your OnInit as well.